# Simplifying QuerySet calls depending on arguments

Tags: django, coding-style

Let's say I have a variable `time_period`, with a value of one of the following strings: `weekly`, `monthly`, `yearly`.

...and a QuerySet call filtering through a model `TimeModel`:

```
time_period = 'monthly'
instance = TimeModel.objects.get(time_period=time_period,
                                 year=datetime.now().year,
                                 month=datetime.now().month)
```

In this case, I've passed the parameters `year` and `month` in, because `time_period == 'monthly'`. If `time_period == yearly`, I would want to only pass `year`, and if `time_period == weekly`, I would pass all three (`yearly`, `monthly`, and `weekly`) in.

Is there any way of doing what I've described short of writing 3 `if` statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
from django.db.models import Q

now = datetime.now()
time_periods = {
    'weekly': Q(year=now.year, month=now.month, day=now.week),  # note from OP: now.week is technically invalid; you actually want to use now.isocalendar()[1]
    'monthly': Q(year=now.year, month=now.month),
    'yearly': Q(year=now.year),
}

instance = TimeModel.objects.get(time_periods[time_period], time_period=time_period)
```

Comment: I get `SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg`. Calling time_periods['monthly'] outside the QuerySet call correctly brings up a `Q` object, however.

Comment: Fixed it by switching the order of the two arguments. I'll go ahead and edit your post.